# How can I overwrite attr_readonly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I have an attribute that is protected using attr_readonly to prevent users from altering the field.

I want to be able to alter it using an instance method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `attr_protected` here instead of `attr_readonly`. Then you will be protected from mass-asignment from forms.

```
#in model
attr_protected :my_field
#in controller
obj = MyModel.new({:my_field => "dsadsad"})
obj.my_field
#=> nil
obj.my_field = "ololo"
obj.my_field
#=> "ololo"
```

**EDIT**

Situation: you need to set `email` only once: while creating user. Then you want to edit email only if you're admin.

```
# Model
attr_protected :email

# Controller
def create
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  @user.email = params[:user][:email]
  @user.save
  respond_with @user
end

def update
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  @user.email = params[:user][:email] if curent_user.admin?
  @user.update_attributes params[:user]
  respond_with @user
end
```

Also check out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible

Comment: But the user needs to be able to modify the attribute during creation. (It's an email field)