# Using both attr_accessible AND attr_readonly does not allow record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, rails-activerecord, mass-assignment

`attr_accessible` marks all non specified attributes as protected, but I need for a few key attributes to still be written on create, as supported by `attr_readonly`.

I have my model setup like so:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bar, :baz
  attr_readonly :shiz
end

class FooParent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos
end

@foo_parent.foos.build(:bar => 1, :baz => 2, :shiz => 3)     # Can't mass-assign protected attribute: :shiz
```

The obvious workaround here would be to not use `attr_readonly`, create the object without the key attributes, then set and save them afterwards. The downside to this approach is that I now have at least 2 writes, and this create method needs to be as performant as humanly possible.

```
@foo_parent.foos.build(:bar => 1, :baz => 2)                 # write #1
@foo_parent.foos.each do |f|
  f.update_attribute(:baz, 3)                                # write #2 and more
end
```

How can I achieve the creation of the object with accessible attributes AND readonly attributes in 1 write without triggering a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes` error, while still enjoying the benefits of the readonly protection after creation?

Comment: May be this is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937702/how-can-i-overwrite-attr-readonly

Comment: No, attr_protected is not what I want because I _DO_ want to mass-assign the readonly variables on create.

Comment: `write #1`, `no write`, `write 1`. I don't understand what these comments mean.

Comment: There are two separate DB write calls, #1 and #2. It was solved below, see the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can substitute `Foo.create` with `Foo.new`.

```
f = Foo.new(:bar => 1, :baz => 2)             # no write
f.update_attribute(:shiz, 3)                     # write 1
```

You can also set `:shiz` as *both* `attr_accessible` and `attr_readonly`.

```
attr_accessible :bar, :baz, :shiz
attr_readonly :shiz

f = Foo.create(bar: 1, baz: 2, shiz: 3)        # write 1
```

If you now try to modify `:shiz` it will not change (as it is readonly):

```
f.update_attribute(:shiz, 15)
f.reload
f.shiz
=> 3
```

Comment: So the code is actually using .build already in one line, then a save. I just mentioned create here for readability. Setting shiz as both accessible and readonly does not work. I am able to apply an update to shiz after creation without getting a mass-assign error as expected.

Comment: I edited the example in the question to show how I am already using build. When build is used as part of the has_many association, it writes during this call

Comment: @coneybeare: This is not correct - although `:shiz` may be passed to `update_attributes` using mass-assignment without an error, it will simply have no effect after creation because it is readonly.  In fact, `attr_readonly` is not designed to ever throw an error.  It simply filters out these attributes from any UPDATE statement rendering them effectively readonly. At the model level, the only way to throw an error for this is to use validators.  See updated.

Comment: I stand corrected. I had a test that kept failing because it did not throw the error when an attempted change was made. when I instead test a reload/val-change, it indeed behaves as intended. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**  see [Mass assignment security](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html)

replace

```
attr_accessible :bar, :baz
```

with

```
attr_accessible :bar, :baz, :shiz
```